# Maintaining sorted arrays of 2D points after splitting (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, split

So far I have an array of 2D points, (x_i, y_i). In the first step I create an array sorted by x-coordinate and array sorted by y-coordinate. Then I split x-sorted array in two halves. 
How do I reconstruct from these two halves the corresponding two halves of y-sorted array without sorting by y-coordinate again.
It seems that it is possible in linear time and should be quite easy. Thanks.

Comment: This is not clear.  Please give an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: A list of points, sorted as you have described into four partitions, and arranged as you expect them to be *when finished* will likely go a long way in clarifying your question. Ideally 6 or more points in your sample.

Comment: Not sure I got it, the problem is I have one array "A" of 2D points.
The input: A_x - array A sorted by x coordinate, A_y - array A sorted by y coordinate. A_x is split in two sorted halves: A_left_x and A_right_x. 
Output: two corresponding sorted halves of A_y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode:

```
for p in sorted-by-y
    if p is in first half of sorted-by-x
        add p to first half of sorted-by-y
    else
        add p to second half of sorted-by-y
```

If you add p to the end of each "half set", then the sort order of "sorted-by-y" will be maintained.